# Java Lambda Iteration List from JPA

Tags: java, jpa, lambda, lazy-evaluation, java-8

I found some strange behaviour when using lambda with JPA, seems java 8 lambda don't iterate when get a list from another object.

For Example:

```
    List<MyObject> list = anotherObject.getMyObjectList(); // Get The List

    list.foreach(myobject -> System.out.println("NOT PRINTED"));

    System.out.println("Size?: " + list.size()); // Print The Size = 2
```

I try with list.stream().foreach() with the same results..

After hours of testing i found a trick

```
    List<MyObject> copyList = new ArrayList<>(list); // copy The List 
    copyList.foreach(myobject -> System.out.println("OMG IS PRINTED!"));
```

Huh? Any ideas?, is this a bug? or im doing something wrong?
My Entity Clases are working good, all the relations are good... :)

Thanks in Advance :).

Comment: Seems like the `List` proxy doesn't intercept the `forEach` call like it should.

Comment: In the example that works, we know that the list is an "ArrayList".  In the example that doesn't work, we don't have enough information to know what type of object it is.  Is it a custom implementation of List?  If so, then the bug is likely in that custom implementation.

Comment: :P Yes the anotherObject.getMyObjectList(); returns a List<MyObject>, is the same Object, is not a custom implementation of list, is the java.util.List, :P

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface, not a class.  What is the concrete list type being returned by `getMyObjectList()`?

Comment: Is it a lazy collection? could you try what happens if you call `list.size()` before the `list.foreach(...)`? Just to initialize the collection.

Comment: @DarkZaioN Do `System.out.println(list.getClass())` to find the concrete class of the List returned by `anotherObject.getMyObjectList()`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to know the concrete class of the List returned by `anotherObject.getMyObjectList()`. It may have a bug in its iterator.

When you copy it to an ArrayList using `new ArrayList<>(list)`, the code for this constructor copies the elements from the source list using `toArray` and then copies that into a new array that's contained within the ArrayList.

When you call `list.forEach`, unless it's been overridden by the concrete class, this ends up calling the default method `forEach` of `Iterable`, whose implementation is:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

This is just a standard enhanced-for loop here, nothing magic. But this for loop is implemented in terms of the list's iterator. Try writing out a for-loop instead of calling `list.forEach(lambda)`, or try calling `list.iterator()` and see how many elements you get out of it. If `toArray` works but the iteration techniques don't, it seems like a bug in the implementation of the JPA list class's iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Update your EclipseLink version, this bug is already fixed!

Bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075

Update to 2.6.0 or higher:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0